# Adding HDD with data on it

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu server 14 on a machine with a small SSD. I have a large HDD full of data from an old Fedora install. When I install the data drive and turn on the Ubuntu box, the HDD shows up and the data is all accessible. gparted says it is an ext4 file system. The mount point is /media/username/long_number_or_random_digits. fstab does not seem to know about the drive.

I gather it is mounted as a removable drive. How to I make it permanent? I'd like to access it by going to /mydrive

Answer (score 3):

You can use `blkid` to get the UUID for the drive, then set that in your `/etc/fstab` to mount your drive each and every time to the same location.

Example:

```
:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Seagate Backup Plus Drive" UUID="6AAA4323AA42EB61" TYPE="ntfs"
```

As we can see the UUID there so take a note of that.  We will use the UUID for the fstab.

Create a mount point for it:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Seagate
```

Now, all I need to do is to add that mount to the `fstab` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the line as follows:

```
UUID=6AAA4323AA42EB61 /media/Seagate ntfs defaults,nofail 0 0
```

If my drive was formatted as `ext4`, I would just change the `ntfs` to `ext4`.  After I save the file with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then all I have to do to get the mount to go right now is `sudo mount -a` if the drive is not mounted.  Every reboot the drive is always mounted now at the same spot.

**EDIT:** It has been brought to my attention that if the drive is not plugged in, the host might go into Maintenance mode before booting all the way up.  Adding `nofail` to the line should work so that it skips that drive during boot if it is not connected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What happens if the device isn't connected at boot will the _fstab_ not report an error ?

Comment: @George Added update to my answer about adding `nofail` to the fstab line.

Comment: Good learning for me.